# Adding Existing Form to C++/CLI WinForms Project

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I have two C++/CLI projects A and B in separate solutions. I use A for experiments/testing and move the tested code to B once I am finished testing. However, I find that on adding a windows forms class (header, cpp and resx) to project B, I am no longer able to use the visual forms designer of the IDE. How do I enable that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it!

1. Open the Solution Explorer pane and
   the Properties pane side-by-side.
2. Select the header file for the form
   class in the Solution Explorer pane.
3. In the properties pane, select "C++
   Form" under the "File Type"
   property.

The header file will now display a form icon next to it's name and will open in the form editor when double clicked.