# How to add existing form to my clr/c++ project in VS2012

Tags: c++, clr, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to attach existing form to my clr project. when I added the  header file, cpp file and resx file. Nothing has happened. and I don't know why. I applied all steps in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584881/adding-existing-form-to-c-cli-winforms-project).

the picture below explains the item type to my header file in my project and there is not  an 
option to convert the item type from c++ form to c++ header.

[Properties to my added header file picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/952Mx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you followed the steps correctly.

For better clarity I have attached a screen shot that illustrates the change.

[image]

Hope that helps!!